# Setting up multiple Jenkins Mac slaves with Jenkins Linux master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I wanted to create ipa files with a Jenkins slave on mac. My Jenkins  master is on Linux.

So when creating a job in master, I need to configure the Xcode plugin. So should I give the path and keychain in the slave?

Or is there a way to create the job in slave and the master triggering it?

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins slaves are just "runners", they don't provide configuration page. All the job configurations are made on the master, even if it's a Linux machine.

Start by setting up a Jenkins slave on the Mac:

- http://www.parsed.io/setup-a-mac-slave-for-jenkins/
- https://blog.samsaodev.com/how-to-setup-a-jenkins-slave-running-mac-osx-for-ios-projects-part-1/